# How to create one update query (mysql) on multiple databases

Tags: mysql, database, update, query

**I have several DBS on the same mysql server.
The DBS's structure and schema are exactly the same (only data is different)**

the query on certain db  **works well** like this (written in phpmyadmin)

```
UPDATE  `mdl_modules` SET `visible`=0 
WHERE `name` IN ("survey","feedback","audio","testing")
```

I thought it could be something like that:

```
UPDATE `db_name1`.`mdl_modules`, `db_name2`.`mdl_modules`,`db_name3`.`mdl_modules`
SET `visible`=0  WHERE `name` 
IN ("survey","feedback","audio","testing")
```

but **this doesn't work** and I get an error
of course I have more that 3 dbs..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use transactions.

```
START TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE  `db_name1`.`mdl_modules` SET `visible`=0 
    WHERE `name` IN ("survey","feedback","audio","testing");
  UPDATE  `db_name2`.`mdl_modules` SET `visible`=0 
    WHERE `name` IN ("survey","feedback","audio","testing");
  UPDATE  `db_name3`.`mdl_modules` SET `visible`=0 
    WHERE `name` IN ("survey","feedback","audio","testing");
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Is there Any way to do it in One sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came up with for this using bash. Its assumes that all the database names are prefixed with `db_` like in your example. Useful if there are lots of duplicate databases and you don't want to define update queries in a transaction for each one.

```
mysql -N -B -e "show databases like 'db_%'" \
| while read line; \
do mysql -B -N \
-e "UPDATE mdl_modules SET visible=0 WHERE name IN ("survey","feedback","audio","testing");" \
$line; done
```